# Ratchet: How to share information between pages?

Tags: javascript, ratchet

I'm currently using the Ratchet framework for UI and was wondering how I would go about sharing information (ex. user inputted data) between pages. The site doesn't seem to cover this and I can't seem to find a tutorial of any sort.

Comment: Ratchet is just a UI layer. You'd share data between pages the same way you would with any other web application, which can be done in multiple ways.

Comment: @Vinay What would you recommend?

Comment: I would recommend you take time to learn how web applications can be structured. This question is much too broad to be able to answer properly. Is your application single-paged? If so, then you can store data in memory via javascript. If not, you can leverage local storage, persisting data in a URL hash, on a server, etc. The list goes on - it just depends on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option here is to use HTML local storage. You can find a very good introduction on how to start here:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp